# Dynamic conditions in formattable

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

I am using formattable to implement some conditional colour formatting in a table in a shiny app. For instance, let's say I want to colour cells below the value 2, green, above 5, red, and between 2 and 5, orange. I would write my formatter function like this:

```
formatter(
  "span", 
  style = x ~ style(
  color = 'white',
  'background-color' =  
    ifelse(x > 5, "red",
      ifelse(x > 2 & x <= 5, "orange",
        "green"))))
```

However, what I really want to do is have those colour threshold values, i.e., 2 and 5, to be able to be changed by the user.

So let's say user_low and user_high are defined by the user:

```
col_format <- 
  formatter(
      "span", 
      style = x ~ style(
      color = 'white',
      'background-color' =  
        ifelse(x > input$user_high, "red",
          ifelse(x > input$user_low & x <= input$user_high, "orange",
            "green"))))
```

If I now try to feed this formatter into formattable inside my shiny app:

```
formattable(mtcars, col_format)
```

I get the following error:

```
'col_format' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Seemingly input$user_low and input$user_high are not evaluated and are instead treated as strings inside the formatter. I've tried eval(), eval(parse()), to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure about `formattable` but this is really easy with `tableHTML`. Check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/conditional_column.html). It also works with shiny.

Comment: Nice @LyzandeR. I hadn't seen tableHTML, definitely a good backup. Formattable looks a bit nicer though, would like to do it in that framework if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost functional, but if you want to use input elements such as `input$user_high` in an expression, you have to use a `reactive`.

This will happen in order:

1. The values of the input elements change. (either `input$user_low`, or `input$user_high`)
2. The column formatting condition (`col_format`) will update because its dependency changed.
3. The `dataTableOutput` is rerendered because it depends on `col_format`.

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("user_low", "User low", value = 2, min = 1, max = 5),
      numericInput("user_high", "User high", value = 8, min = 6, max = 10)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable( {
    as.datatable(formattable(mtcars, list(
      cyl = col_format()
    )))
  })

  col_format <- reactive( {
    formatter(
      "span",
      style = x ~ style(
        color = 'white',
        'background-color' =
          ifelse(x > input$user_high, "red",
                 ifelse(x > input$user_low & x <= input$user_high, "orange",
                        "green"))))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit**: To apply the formatter to every column (as per your comment), you can use `lapply` as shown in the **Dynamically generating formatters** section in the [Formattable vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html). The code below applies the formatting to the whole dataset.

Code:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable( {
  as.datatable(formattable(mtcars, lapply(1:ncol(mtcars), function(col) {
    area(row = 1:nrow(mtcars), col) ~ col_format() 
  })))
})
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that @GyD. I did actually try putting the formatter inside a reactive and it didn't work, but I realise now it was because I was trying to apply the formatter to every column (not just `cyl`, as in your answer). I probably should have mentioned that. I will mark the question as answered but if you have any idea on how to apply the formatter to every column of mtcars it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @quantumcatz you can use `lapply` for that, since you need to provide a list to `formattable`. See my edited answer for specifics.